# Microsoft Access - SQL Distinct reference in table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Sorry if this has already been answered. I looked around but haven't found anything that really worked.

Basically, I want to get all the data based on distinct in a column in a table from access

So I've written the following code:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table t where t.refnum IN (select distinct refnum from table)")
```

This makes sense in sql but I'm unable to get the desired results in Access.

Comment: I have no problem with that SQL statement in Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're inner query is distinct.  But then your outer query un-distincts it :-).

`*` means you want every field in the table.  If you have duplicates records at that level, then you have a table with no unique record id, which *might* be a bad design.

Anyway -- a distinct return goes like this:

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT min(refnum), [field1], [field2] FROM table GROUP BY [field1], [Field2])
```

You don't need the inner/outer query like you have it -- just this.

Also -- just standard advice -- you might do better to list the fields, rather than use *.

**EDIT**
I added group by to the sql above.  Also, you do need to list-out the fields now -- can't use `*`.  Also, remember that fields you aggregate (such as refnum, when you use min() on it) should not be listed in your GROUP BY.

Comment: I'm getting ther error "Cannot group on fields selected with '*'.
I would list the fields but there are over 100.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters but it's the 5th column in the list

Comment: sorry -- i forgot the group by -- will ammend my answer

Comment: I didn't want to list out the fileds (100+) so I went a different way. By removing the earlier times in another field removing the duplicate entries. there's always another way around a problem. Thanks for your help - Answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from table t where t.refnum IN (select refnum from table group by refnum)")

Comment: I tried this and wasn't geting what was required. see above.
Thanks for your help